# Is the only even number a coincidence?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

$$n^n\cdot n!+1$$ is prime for $$n=1,3,7,13,23,55,90,337,2313$$ and no other $n\le 4\ 500$

The only even such $n$ out of $9$ in this search range is $90$.

> Is this a coincidence and can it be expected that further $n$ giving a prime are even , or is there an explanation why odd numbers $n$ are preferred ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136843/discussion-on-question-by-peter-is-the-only-even-number-a-coincidence).